# Delete helm3 app/release without deleting the helm2 app/release

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am migrating helm2 releases to helm3 using helm 2to3 plugin. I need to be able to repeat the migration steps in the dev or test environment. Once I have the release migrated/converted to helm3, I need to uninstall it but running the `helm3 uninstall` will also uninstall the `helm2` app. How do I remove the `helm3` release without affecting the `helm2`?

Comment: Are you referring to the output of `helm list`, or the actual Kubernetes resources?

Comment: The actual kubernetes resources